# PHP url variable passing prints variable name not the value

Tags: php, html, variables, get

I'm trying to pass a string through the url to be printed through an echo statement in another php page but it prints the variable name rather than the value

page1:

```
<p><?php $first = $row['post'];
    $string = substr($row['post'], 0, 200);
    echo $string;
    ?></p>

    </header>
    <a href="#" class="image main"><img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <ul class="actions special">
    <a href="article.php?posters='.$first.'" class="button large">
        Full Story</a>
```

This it the code where I'm trying to pass the variable first's value through the url to the next page

Page 2:

```
<p><?php echo $_GET['posters'];?></p>
```

This is how I call it in page 2 and the result printed on the page is

```
'.$first.'
```

How do I get it to print the actual value of the variable `$first` and not the name.

Comment: `<a href="article.php?posters='.$first.'" class="button large">` <- this is html not php.

Comment: `<a href="article.php?posters=<?php echo $first ?>" class="button large">`

Comment: Besides the answer(s) in form of comments; this looks to be database related. I hope you're using a prepared statement for all this. Wouldn't want your db to disappear one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
<a href="article.php?posters=<?php echo $first ?>" class="button large">Full Story</a>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP did not mention a value for `$row['post']` I arbitraily picked one and manipulated it in assigning a value to `$first`, as follows:

```
<p><?php 
$row['post'] = "The rain in Spain stays mainly in the plain";
$first = substr($row['post'], -5, 5);
?></p>
</header>
<a href="#" class="image main"><img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<ul class="actions special">
<a href="article.php?posters=<?=urlencode($first) ?>" class="button large">
    Full Story</a>
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/QQ5fS)

The **a** tag is HTML and doesn't attribute any special meaning to a dot, unlike PHP which considers it as a concatenation operator, so you should remove the two dots.

In order for the PHP value of the variable to appear when embedding PHP in HTML (not the best practice these days; check-out [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)), there are two ways.  One is to use **echo** but there is also a shorthand that works, too which this example uses, namely `<?=$first`.

Note: when constructing a url, good practice involves using [urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode). Also, you don't need the single quotes in the query string portion of the url; single quotes prevent string interpolation of a variable's value so instead what you see is the literal variable name.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 

//single quoutes return variable name

$first = "hello";
echo '$first'; //$first

//double quoutes return variable value
$first = "hello";
echo "$first" ;  // hello

?>
```

so in Page 1 
you must use double quotes

```
<a href="article.php?posters=<?php echo $first ?>" class="button large"> Full Story</a>
```